# how to create a VAPI-XP test case using javascript/VBscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, alm, hp-quality-center

I am trying to create an test case in new trial version of  HP ALM 12.5  as  test type (VAPI-XP test)

Step1. Chose the  Script type ( Vbscript, JScript, PerlScript)

Step 2. Choose the  console of the   application (COM/DOM console / Java Class/ SOAP web console)

Step3. For my Curretn Scenario , I am trying to create a javaScript and Select my console as ( Java Class)

Step 4: Click on NEXT and when i am trying to  add my Java class i'm facing an  Error as "MSJVM should be installed in the Machine"

So far  i have resarched link  I hear the  MSJVM is outdated currenlty . No  recent  version of MSJVM is being released.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Java_Virtual_Machine.

If any one has known  solutions or any guided steps to follow . Please suggest me.

Thanks,
AJ

[ERRORPIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiOch.png)

Answer (score 0):

Java scripts are not supported because redistribution of Microsoft JVM is illegal since the law suit between MS and SUN . And other JVMs cannot interop with QC/ALM COM object (the OTA APIs)

If your java classes don't need to call OTA APIs, you can just create VAPI-XP test in VBscript or Python/Perl then invoke your java apps by them.